# Source trait is inaccessible

Tags: rust, visibility, traits

The situation is (severely simplified) this ([playpen](http://is.gd/vxViAu)):

```
mod tokentree {
    pub struct TokenTree;
    mod serialize {
        use std::collections::BTreeMap;
        use super::TokenTree;
        #[derive(Debug)]
        pub struct InternStr;
        pub trait InternStrsExt {
            fn intern_strs(&self) -> BTreeMap<&str, InternStr>;
        }
        impl InternStrsExt for [TokenTree] {
            fn intern_strs(&self) -> BTreeMap<&str, InternStr> { BTreeMap::new() }
        }
    }
    pub use self::serialize::{InternStrsExt, InternStr};
}
use tokentree::*;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", [TokenTree].intern_strs());
}
```

I get the following error (both on nightly and beta):

```
<anon>:20:22: 20:47 error: source trait is inaccessible
<anon>:20     println!("{:?}", [TokenTree].intern_strs());
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My problem is that I don't even know what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a pub declaration. Also your declarations are all over the place. Recommended form is to stick your `pub mod` declarations first, then, `use`.

Here is the working example.

```
mod tokentree {
    pub struct TokenTree;
    pub mod serialize {
        use std::collections::BTreeMap;
        use super::TokenTree;
        #[derive(Debug)]
        pub struct InternStr;
        pub trait InternStrsExt {
            fn intern_strs(&self) -> BTreeMap<&str, InternStr>;
        }
        impl InternStrsExt for [TokenTree] {
            fn intern_strs(&self) -> BTreeMap<&str, InternStr> { BTreeMap::new() }
        }
    }
    pub use self::serialize::{InternStrsExt, InternStr};
}
pub use tokentree::*;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", [TokenTree].intern_strs());
}
```

([playpen](http://is.gd/ojajUZ))

What happened here is that you stumbled upon following glitches:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18241
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16264

You can't export your traits from a private module. That's why you need to change  `mod serialize` into `pub mod serialize`. For example this [playpen example](http://is.gd/wKD8gC) demonstrates that exporting `struct Export` works, but un-commenting the `println!` will make it stop compiling, because we used a trait.

Tip: One thing that helps me with the visibility rules is to generate doc files and see which doc files are visible.

Comment: I still don't understand why `serialize` needs to be public, even though everything referenced in the trait (`InternStr`, and obviously `BTreeMap`) is visible to the crate root where it's used. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @CrystalGamma I've tracked down the behavior. The problem is Trait reexport. Pub struct behaves as you thought it would, but Traits are a another bag of crazy.

Comment: To solve the problem, I only had to make the module in which the trait is public `pub mod my_trait`